# Copying SELECT data into columns in same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

If have a `SELECT` statement that is designed to take an existing column and split it into two new ones:

```
SELECT IIf(InStr(1,[First Name]," ")>0,Left([First Name],InStr(1,[First Name]," ")),[First Name]) AS Fname, 
IIf(InStr(1,[First Name]," ")>0,Mid([First Name],InStr(1,[First Name]," ")+1),NULL) AS Mname
FROM Pupils;
```

I've added the columns *Fname* and *Mname* to the table. How can I copy the data returned from the `SELECT` into the new columns on the same table?

Answer (score 1):

Reuse those `IIf` expressions from your `SELECT` query in an `UPDATE` query.

```sql
UPDATE Pupils
SET
    Fname = IIf(
        InStr(1,[First Name]," ")>0,
        Left([First Name],InStr(1,[First Name]," ")),
        [First Name]
        ),
    Mname = IIf(
        InStr(1,[First Name]," ")>0,
        Mid([First Name],InStr(1,[First Name]," ")+1),
        NULL
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Update with Join

```
Update M
set M.NewCol1=D.Fname 
  M.NewCol2=D.Mname
from  MainTable M
JOIN
(
SELECT IIf(InStr(1,[First Name]," ")>0,Left([First Name],InStr(1,[First Name]," ")),[First Name]) AS Fname, 
IIf(InStr(1,[First Name]," ")>0,Mid([First Name],InStr(1,[First Name]," ")+1),NULL) AS Mname
FROM Pupils)D
ON M.col1 = D.col1
```